# I don't understand where the id comes from when creating a new json element in a form (React Hooks)

Tags: reactjs, json, typescript, forms, json-server

I have a CRUD form with React Hooks that works correctly, the problem is that I have not indicated that the item is created with a unique ID and yet it has it. Having a unique ID is something that interests me, but I don't understand where it comes from. Does any part of the code cause it to be created? I'm very confused.

Im using JSON Server.

This is the json:

```
{
  "posts": [
    {
      "id": 15,
      "title": "ho",
      "author": "Autor de ejemplo",
      "content": "Contenido."
    }
  ]
}
```

This is the fetch with the POST method:

```
export function setPost(posts: IPost) {
  return fetch('http://localhost:3004/posts', {
    method: 'POST',
    headers: {
      'Content-Type': 'application/json'
    },
    body: JSON.stringify(posts)
  })
    .then(response => response.json())
}
```

And this is the form:

```
interface ErrorMessageProps {
    message: string;
}

const ErrorMessage: React.FC<ErrorMessageProps> = props => {
    return (
        <div className="errorEmpty">
            {props.message}
        </div>
    );
};

const New: React.FC = () => {
    const [newPost, setNewPost] = useState({
        id: Number(''),
        title: '',
        author: '',
        content: ''
    })
    const [error, setError] = useState('')

    let navigate = useNavigate();

    const handleInputChange = (e: React.FormEvent<HTMLInputElement>) => {
        console.log((e.target as HTMLInputElement).value)
        setNewPost({
            ...newPost,
            [(e.target as HTMLInputElement).name]: (e.target as HTMLInputElement).value
        })
    };

    const createPost = (e: React.FormEvent<HTMLFormElement>) => {
        e.preventDefault();
        if (!newPost.title || !newPost.author || !newPost.content) {
            setError("¡No dejes campos vacíos!")
        } else {
            setPost(newPost);
            navigate("/");
        }
    }

    return (
        <div className="containerHomepage">
            <form className="formulari" onSubmit={createPost}>
                <div className="containerBreadCrumb">
                    <ul className="breadCrumb">
                        <li>Posts</li>
                    </ul>
                </div>

                <div className="containerTitleButton">
                    <input
                        className=""
                        type="text"
                        placeholder='Post title'
                        name="title"
                        onChange={handleInputChange}
                    ></input>
                    <button
                        className="button"
                        type="submit"
                    >Save</button>
                </div>

                <div className="containerEdit">
                    <input
                        className="editAuthor"
                        type="text"
                        placeholder='Author'
                        name="author"
                        onChange={handleInputChange}
                    ></input>
                    <input
                        className="editContent"
                        type="textarea"
                        placeholder='Content'
                        name="content"
                        onChange={handleInputChange}
                    ></input>
                    < ErrorMessage
                        message={error}
                    />
                </div>

            </form>
        </div>
    );
};


// ========================================

export default New;
```

Comment: I don't see anywhere in this frontend code where you assign an `id` property other than in the initial `newPost` state value. `Number('')` evaluates to `0`. It seems likely that the backend is assigning post ids when you POST new posts there. Can you share the backend POST Api on `"/posts"`?

Comment: I don't have any backend because im using JSON server and as far as I know, json server doesn't create ID's automatically.

Comment: What/where are you POST'ing these requests to? Is this something JSON server is handling that you are just not aware of? Do you have a links to the docs?

Comment: https://www.npmjs.com/package/json-server I see, it's a JSON backed database. My guess is that when you POST to the API it's generating the `id` property for you.